# Struggling with installation of Raspbian on SD card from a Windows 8 machine

Tags: raspbian, hardware, sd-card, image

I am a first timer asking question here, and also a new Raspberry Pi user (well, potential user).

So, I bought a new Raspberry Pi 2 with 16 GB SD Card yesterday. The SD card was without Noobs, so I am trying to install a Raspbian OS image on my SD card. As instructed on the website, I tried following the steps:

- Downloaded a zip file of Raspbian image
- Extracted the zip file
- Downloaded Win32DiskImager

Now when I try to write Raspbian image to my SD card I am getting this below exception

> error 1117: the request could not be performed because of an I/O devise error

I did some google, and found out that this might be because of wrong format of SDCard and I should use `CHKDSK`. But now even that isn't working fine.

```
CHKDSK G: /f
error: Access denied as you do not have sufficient permissions
```

(I am running CMD prompt as administrator)

```
CHKDSK G: /r /f
```

Same error as above.

I am not sure if I following the right path while installation. Can some please guide.

[image: Write Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that sometimes boot sectors of a memory card can not be accessed from Laptop's inbuilt Memory Card reader. Buying a external memory card reader helped me to format my SD Card, and my rasperry pi is working very well now.

Thanks for the help guys!!

Comment: Did you mean "cannot be accessed"?

Comment: Yes, Jacob. That was excitement I guess. Edit done.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

As the instructions on the Raspberry Pi website say (http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/), you should format your SD card first before trying to copy an image onto it. The link to the recommended formatting tool is included on that walkthrough page. Have you tried doing this before copying the image to the SD card?